# Deleting an element using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

everyone! I am a novice for html/css/javascript.
I am learning this kind of courses on Coursera.
In the program, I try to use "theRightSide" to copy "theLeftSide" and delete the last image in "theRightSide".
I have tried every method for two days. But cannot fix it.
Chrome says that "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null".
Can anyone tell me where the bug is? Great thanks!!!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            img {position: absolute;}
            div {position: absolute;width: 500px;height: 500px;}
            #rightside {left: 500px;border-left: 1px solid black;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="generateFaces()">
        <h1>Matching Game</h1>
        <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left</p>
        <div id="leftside"></div>
        <div id="rightside"></div>
        <script>
            var numberOfFaces=5;
            var theLeftSide=document.getElementById("leftside");
            var theRightSide=document.getElementById("rightside");

            function generateFaces(){
                for (var i = 0; i <numberOfFaces; i++) {
                    var pic=document.createElement("img");
                    pic.src="smile.png";
                    pic.style.top=Math.random()*400+"px";
                    pic.style.left=Math.random()*400+"px";
                    theLeftSide.appendChild(pic);

                };
            }
            var leftSideImages=theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
            var last_child=leftSideImages.lastChild;
            last_child.parentNode.removeChild(last_child);
            theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);       
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Decent browsers have [`node.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) and instead of `lastChild` you might want to use `lastElementChild` to be sure it's not a text node or white space.

Comment: The `body.onload` event handler fires later, when the body has finished loading, and that's when you add the elements to the left side, but you're trying to move those elements on pageload, when they aren't there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Like **@adeneo** explained in comment:  *The `body.onload` event handler fires later, when the body has finished loading, and that's when you add the elements to the left side, but you're trying to move those elements on pageload, when they aren't there yet.*

So what you have to do is to add the code that use the childs of `leftside` after the loop that append those childs (inside the function `generateFaces()`) so it can find this childs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put the lastchild inside the function of body load:

```
function generateFaces(){
            for (var i = 0; i <numberOfFaces; i++) {
                var pic=document.createElement("img");
                pic.src="smile.png";
                pic.style.top=Math.random()*400+"px";
                pic.style.left=Math.random()*400+"px";
                theLeftSide.appendChild(pic);

            };
            var leftSideImages=theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
            var last_child=leftSideImages.lastChild;
            last_child.parentNode.removeChild(last_child);
            theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages); 
        }
```

It is triggering before having images.
The function generateFaces() is starting after loading the body, but the rest of the code runs as soon as possible, so when it runs there are no childs in it yet.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The function runs later than the code below it,if you log the value of `leftSideImages` after you assigned it you would see that it contains no children.

One way of doing it is putting the code inside the function.

Code:

```
            var numberOfFaces=5;
            var theLeftSide=document.getElementById("leftside");
            var theRightSide=document.getElementById("rightside");

            function generateFaces(){
                for (var i = 0; i <numberOfFaces; i++) {
                    var pic=document.createElement("img");
                    pic.src="smile.png";
                    pic.style.top=Math.random()*400+"px";
                    pic.style.left=Math.random()*400+"px";
                    theLeftSide.appendChild(pic);

                };

                var leftSideImages=theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
                console.log(leftSideImages);
                var last_child=leftSideImages.lastChild;
                last_child.parentNode.removeChild(last_child);
                theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages); 
            }
```

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgoxXm?editors=101)

Comment: Np :) be sure to accept the answer if you deem it helpful.